# Unique values in MongoDb array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying find unique ObjectIds from monogdb ObjectId array using filter. For some reason I am not getting unique array back. Is there is some other way to get unique array back ?

```
var objIds = [  5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754, 
                5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382752, 
                5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754, 
                5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382751
             ]
```

Here is the filter code

```
objIds = objIds.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i)
```

I am expecting following array after filter

```
[  5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754, 
   5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382752, 
   5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382751
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in an array and the elements inside the array is a string then this should work.

```
function getUniqueValues(arr) {
  return arr.filter((e, i) => arr.indexOf(e) === i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniq) `uniq` method to do this easily.

```
const { uniq } = require("lodash");
var objIds = [
    "5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754",
    "5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382752",
    "5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754",
    "5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382751"
];

console.log(uniq(objIds));
```

will give the following output

```
[ '5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382754',
  '5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382752',
  '5ad3509fbb426a4f4a382751' ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to avoid ObjectId to sting conversion. uniq does not work with objectIds